# Percentile Calculation

Tags: statistics

I have a series of data. let's say these are scores of various schools  (51.3%, 51.3%, 62.5%, 64%, 68%, 71.3%, 84.5%, 86%, 88.7%, 90%, 91.3%). For this, All I need to calculate percentile for each school.
What is easiest way to find?

Comment: Note that there are multiple ways of computing percentiles. For a large number of data these give approximately the same result, but you have a small number of data. See http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc262.htm . If this is an exercise for school, you should consult your textbook or course notes for a formula so that you use the desired method.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the definition of a percentile first:

"A percentile is a value on a scale of $100$ that indicates the percent of a distribution that is equal to or below it." – Merriam-Webster

According to this definition, the $1$st percentile includes everything that is within **$1$ percent or less**, the $2$nd percentile includes everything that is **$2$ percent or less**, and so on.

All you have to do is to round up the numbers to the nearest whole number. This is because something like $51.3$% *is not in the $51$st percentile* or less, but in the $52$nd percentile.

Answer (score 0):

Write the rank of each school. After that apply formula

```
 Percentile = ((position of school)/total no. Of school participating - 1))*100
```

I did -1 because in total the school(of which the percentile is calculated) is never included.

Now you will think why percentile is not 100 for first ranked school. Fyi percentile never comes 100. For very big no. Of participants it may approaches to 99.999...... but never 100.

Hope you got it from here.

Comment: Bhai Yaar upvote karde.